# Calling into AVFoundation on a background thread interferes with SwiftUI animation

Tags: animation, swiftui, avfoundation, actor

I have an app with an animation stutter that I've distilled down to the following reproduction:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AnimatingCircle()
            Button("Trigger animation stutter") {
                Task {
                    await MyActor().go()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct AnimatingCircle: View {
    @State var shouldAnimate = false
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(.red)
            .animation(.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                $0.scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.5 : 0.5)
            }
            .onAppear {
                shouldAnimate = true
            }
    }
}

final actor MyActor {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    func go() {
        let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
            deviceTypes: [.microphone],
            mediaType: .audio,
            position: .unspecified
        ).devices.first!
        captureSession.addInput(try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone))
        captureSession.addOutput(AVCaptureAudioDataOutput())
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

When the button is tapped, there is a very noticeable stutter in the circle animation. I have verified that all the AVFoundation calls I make are on a background thread. I'm at a loss for how to work around this.

First, how is it possible that the AVFoundation code is interfering with the animation? Does it imply that something in the workings of AVFoundation is dispatching back to the main thread?

Second, any ideas on working around this?

Tap here to see the animation result (the animation is annoying):

> [image]

**Update 1**

I appreciate the scrutiny of my use of Tasks and Actors, but that is not the cause. The same bug is exhibited with this code:

```swift
Button("Trigger animation stutter") {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        go()
    }
}

func go() {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
        deviceTypes: [.microphone],
        mediaType: .audio,
        position: .unspecified
    ).devices.first!
    captureSession.addInput(try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone))
    captureSession.addOutput(AVCaptureAudioDataOutput())
    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

Comment: I don't own an iPhone to test this. I've tried on simulator only... Try using this: Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
                    await MyActor().go()
                }.    I've also noticed that the go() function is not async.

Comment: In SwiftUI it's `.task` not `Task{}` and if you want a background thread await an async func that is nonisolated

Comment: @MatBuompy same behavior with `Task.detached(priority:)`. As for `go` not being async: none of the calls to AVFoundation are async. I am calling into the AVFoundation synchronous calls on a background thread, which to my knowledge is guaranteed by the definition `actor MyActor`

Comment: @malhal same behavior with `.task`. I have also verified with `NSThread.isMainThread` in the body of `go` that it is not executing on main

Comment: @LouZell I added an answer with code demonstrating what I meant

Comment: @malhal thanks! Same result though. I hadn't used that trick of state to trigger a `Task` before, so that's at least a learning! For the bug, I really think it is unrelated to my use of concurrency APIs. See my "update 1" for an example, where I revert to GCD and the bug is still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, it has something to do with **the debugger**. I did not see that one coming.

If I turn off 'debug executable', the stutter is completely gone. This is good news in that customers of the live app will not encounter the degraded experience.

[image: Turn off 'Debug executable']

I spent so much time on this. I modified my audio code to follow the guide [Capturing stereo audio from built-in microphones](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/capturing_stereo_audio_from_built-in_microphones) hoping that the bug was in AVCaptureSession and not present in AVAudioSession. Same exact result.

So if you are building with AVCaptureSession or AVAudioSession and you experience apparent main thread blocking, try unchecking this box before you spend a bunch of time refactoring.

Comment: I opened feedback FB13518544 (maybe someone from Apple will see this)

Answer (score 2):

To get your async await code correct it’s this:

```
@State var capturing = false
…
Button("Capture") {
     capturing.toggle()
}
.task(id: capturing) {
    if capturing == false {
        return
    }

    await go()
    capturing = false
}
…
nonisolated func go() async {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
            deviceTypes: [.microphone],
            mediaType: .audio,
            position: .unspecified
        ).devices.first!
        captureSession.addInput(try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone))
        captureSession.addOutput(AVCaptureAudioDataOutput())
    captureSession.startRunning()
    
    try? await Task.sleep(forever) // up to you max time
}
```

Regarding the stutter, maybe internally the discover goes onto main thread (as is often the case with legacy frameworks) so perhaps track which line causes it down by moving the session config line by line into a global computed var or custom singleton. If that’s the case then configure the session enough before showing the view with the button so tapping button doesn’t do anything that causes the stutter.

Comment: It's not the `discover` but the `startRunning` line that causes the stutter, including in this version. Reworking the code as you suggest is possible. I'll need to make the animation start after `startRunning` returns, or perhaps wait for the animation to finish before starting the session. I'm still surprised that such an obvious stutter is caused by invoking an AVFoundation API on a background thread. Looks like I'll start restructuring haha

Comment: I'll also file a bug report with Apple

Comment: See my answer if you want to laugh or cry. No need to restructure the code. Thanks for trying to help, this one was super strange!

Comment: Yes I think thread pool size is 1 when debugging

Comment: There are more than one. It would be hard to develop a multi threaded app if we only had access to one thread during development :) You can see all the threads running in the debug configuration with cmd+7, then tap CPU